# Using pure javascript to set age verification popup cookie?

Tags: javascript

I am using a new setup for an eCommerce website that requires age verification popup. Usually i would rely on Jquery for that. However my new setup has its own complicated framework and I dont want to inject Jquery into the site just for this one popup. So i was wondering if it can also be done just using pure javascript?

Here is the Jquery version I am used to using: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgarjL

Here is the Jquery code from my pen above

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // put the popup at the start of the body
  $('#ageWrapper').prependTo($('body'));

  // check if the age has already been verified
  if (($.cookie('age')) !== 'true') { $('#ageWrapper').addClass('ageConfirmed'); }

  // if the "yes" button is clicked, add a cookie and hide the popup
  $('#ageOkay').click(function() {
    $.cookie('age', 'true', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    $('#ageWrapper').removeClass('ageUnknown');
  });

  // if the "no" button is clicked, take the user elsewhere
  $('#ageBad').click(function() {
    window.location.href='https://google.com';
  });
});
```

There are many jquery versions/solutions online and even on stack overflow. However I am having trouble finding a Pure Javascript solution.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way it could be solved. Take a careful look to understand what is happening:

```
/* Prepared function that will be checking if the Cookie exists (it will be called in the next function) */
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return;
}

/* Conditional and function to check if Cookie doesn't exist. If so, it creates the Cookie */
if (getCookie('areYouOver18') !== 'yes') {
  function createCookie(name,value,minutes) {
    if (minutes) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = ""; // if time was not declared, the Cookie will expire next time browser closes
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+";"+expires+"; path=/";
  }

  createCookie('areYouOver18', 'yes', (60*48));
  // Cookie's name is "areYouOver18"
  // Cookie's value is "yes"
  // Cookie's expiry time is "48 hours"

  yourFunction(); // The Cookie is created. Now this function can invoke modal
}

function yourFunction () {
  // your function calling modal or doing something else
}
```